# Twitter Video Upload Java

Tags: java, twitter, multipartform-data

Am trying to upload video using Java on twitter and it keeps failing for same reason {"errors":[{"code":214,"message":"Bad request."}]}.

Twitter says the video needs to base64-encoded chunk of media file. My code below for uploading the same

```
    String url = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?command=APPEND&media_id="+mediaId+"&segment_index=0";

    CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(this.consumerKey, this.consumerSecret); 
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token,tokenSecret);

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    request.setHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");


    MultipartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity () ;

    /*
    multiPartEntity.addPart("command", new StringBody("APPEND")) ;
    multiPartEntity.addPart("media_id", new StringBody(mediaId)) ;
    */

    //FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file) ;
    byte[] file64 = loadFileAsBytesArray(file);
    ContentBody cd = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(file64), file.getName());
    multiPartEntity.addPart("media_data",  cd);

    /*
    multiPartEntity.addPart("media_data", cd) ;
    multiPartEntity.addPart("segment_index", new StringBody("0") ) ;
     */
    request.setEntity(multiPartEntity);
    consumer.sign(request);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

    int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    System.err.println("Code "+code);
```

---

```
 public static byte[] loadFileAsBytesArray(File file) throws Exception 
{
    int length = (int) file.length();
    BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    reader.read(bytes, 0, length);
    reader.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

I am able to get the media id, so am sure the authorization if fine. Am I missing something in uploading the base 64 file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I unerstand, once we upload media to media/upload.json end point, we have to make another call to statuses/update_with_media.json endpoint by passing 
mediaId returned above which will post the media to twitter with the status also...Please correct and suggest...

Comment: This isn't really an answer and should probably have been made as a comment to the question.