# Unable to upload video to twitter

Tags: java

[Snip from POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgMbE.png)   I am trying to upload a video to twitter using Java.

I have checked the `tiwtter4j`/`twitvid` kind of third party APIs and also tried to directly use the twitter API. Either ways are not working for me. I am receiving `Could not authenticate you` or `Bad request data` kind of error messages when I am trying to make INIT call to `media/upload.json` endpoint for chunked video upload. Can someone help me on how to successfully upload a video to twitter using Java ?

I am constructing URLs for twitter manually and using `Postman`/`Fiddler` to invoke the URL. I am able to call `request_token` and `access_token` endpoints successfully.
However, when I call media/upload.json, I receive `Could not authenticate you`  errors.

URL: `https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?command=INIT&total_bytes=10240&media_type=video/mp4`

Authorization header :

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXXXX",oauth_nonce="aabddaa4056e4870981dfbb6cf9a5b8a",oauth_signature="UIRqIBkPeaFSlf0cFodQQIaFdzI%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1492497052",oauth_token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",oauth_version="1.0"
```

I am trying to work with the code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422875/twitter-video-upload-java?rq=1) as well, changing the URL from APPEND to INIT but I still get 401 responses.

Comment: Edited the question accordingly. Thank you for your patience and please help me resolve this issue...

Comment: Edit your question by adding your code snippet and highlight the part which does not work as expected.

Comment: Added the URL and Authorization header I am using to hit the service...The Java code that I am using is copied from some online sources like stackoverflow...Thanks

Comment: Please remove this thread from On Hold. I am waiting for some one to help me on this issue..I want to know the authorization header that should be sent along with INIT request...

Comment: @harishbollina I've reformatted your question a little, please check that I didn't mistakenly remove any information. Your question is being voted for reopening, with 3 votes (on 5 needed) it should probably be reopened soon. I could also be a good idea to show some of your code and full stacktraces as some errors could be easier to spot that way

Comment: @Aaron Thank you for your consideration. Unfortunately, I am using Fiddler to submit the request and the response will be only the error code...It is the same error, if I try from a java program...I am using java code from the same thread that I mentioned in the actual question...

Comment: @harishbollina I have voted to reopen this question.

Comment: @harishbollina allright, I didn't know what fiddler was. I guess you provided all the relevant informations, but if you're not sure you could consider adding a screenshot of the tool's request parameter

Comment: Thank you so much...hoping my issue will be resolved soon....

Comment: @Aaron  I have added a snip of my tool...Thanks